# C# Selenium WebDriver get text from label

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I will try to be specific as possible as there is not a lot of code logic I can show. The application I am using I have created a customer within an application using RandomData that I don't know before hand. Once the customer is created there is a label that displays which i have captured via WebElement, for the sake of the example we will call it "lblWebElement". The Webelement is wrapped by a span id. in the span ID tags contains the data i am trying to capture to use for later. each piece of data is seperated by pipes so it looks like this:

```
location | ID | Name | Address | etc.
```

is there a way to capture each data point between the pipes and assign it a String Value to use for later?

Comment: Can you share your HTML? Is it something like:-- 

`<span>location | ID | Name | Address | etc</span>`

Comment: Correct!  -- <span id = "some id info"> location | ID | Name | Address | etc. </span>

Comment: So whats the issue here... you can get the text using `getText()` method provided by selenium and store it in a string variable and then you can split the String using pipe as a delimiter. It should help.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am confused on. In C#, what syntax am I using first to capture the text b/c i am unable to find the getText() in C#  and also I am not familiar with how to split the string up and assign it to variables. Can you explain this via the Syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text using below code:-

```
string text = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("Your Xpath").Text;
```

To Split a String you can use:-

```
string[] values = text.Split('|');
```

Iterate on the `array` to get different values.

Hope it helps!