# Selenium: How to get text out of a div

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get a text which is inside a div. I tried to find help from other questions, but most of them say `.getText()` which doesnt exist anymore.

This is the inspect:
[image]

Im using a chrome extension with which i can copy out the XPath, but it doesnt reads the text inside the div. It copies me this here:

```
//div[@class='mud-alert-message']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get innertext of a DIV using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903993/how-to-get-innertext-of-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: The problem is that you've tagged this question as Java but you are using C#. That's why `.getText()` doesn't exist. You need `driver.FindElement(...).Text;`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Selenium WebDriver get text from label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580442/c-sharp-selenium-webdriver-get-text-from-label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the text ***Die Datei...*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.mud-alert-message")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mud-alert-message']")).getText());
  ```

Ideally, to extract the text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.mud-alert-message"))).getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='mud-alert-message']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```

Comment: getText() doesnt work at xpath. It has a red underline that getText() doesnt exist

Comment: Oh but this works `IWebElement test = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='mud-alert-message']"));
            string text = test.GetAttribute("innerHTML");`

Thanks!!!

Comment: @Beardy `getText()` is a method of the `IWebElement` interface. You must obtain an instance of `WebElement` in order to have access to this method.

Comment: @Beardy Your question tagged with _Java_ and possibly you mentioned about `getText()` that's why the answer was in _java_. Had your question being tagged with `C#`, I would have suggested `.Text` i.e. the text attribute or `GetAttribute("innerHTML")`

Answer (score -1):

I believe is something like this:

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, ...).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeXXX(By.LOCATOR_TYPE));
String text = element.getText();
```

Comment: It says "Non-Invocable member "IWebElement.text" cannot be used like a method. Im using it in C#

Comment: I think it is `getText()`

Comment: @Beardy it is `getText()` and the API has not changed as far as I can see. This method should be available. I am not sure what you saw or where you saw this problem. But the method is still valid.